# Cant push object into array

Tags: angular

I have an issue with my Angular toDoApp project. I have 3 components (app,task-form.task-list). App component receives the final logic from other components. But when I try to push the final object into array, it says that the object values are undefined.

```
   export interface  toDoInterface {
        tittle: string,
        description:string;
    }

 ----------

 export class AppComponent {

  toDoList = [];      //**It returns undefined value**

  newToDo (formData: toDoInterface) {
    this.toDoList.push({
    tittle: formData.tittle,
    description: formData.description
  });  
 }
}

----------

  export class TaskFormComponent implements OnInit {

 @Output() toDo = new EventEmitter<{newTittleValue: string, newDescValue:string}>();

  tittleValue = '';
  descValue = '';

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  addToList () {

  this.toDo.emit({newTittleValue:this.tittleValue,newDescValue:this.descValue})

  }  
}


----------

export class TaskListComponent implements OnInit {

 @Input() name: toDoInterface;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Comment: Try: toDoList: any[] = []; Just a suggestion.

Comment: still returns undefined values.

Comment: Are you handling the `$event` response param correctly?? https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are emitting a different object then you expecting to receive in your `app.component.ts` file `newToDo` method.

You emit the following object:

```
{
  newTittleValue: string;
  newDescValue: string;
}
```

But when you add it to your list you use the following structure (in your case the toDoInterface interface):

```
{
  tittle: string;
  description: string;
}
```

You want to use a parameter from the passed in `formData` object that doesn't exist.

The solutions is simple. Use the interface as the type of your `EventEmitter`.

Like so and so:

```
@Output() toDo = new EventEmitter<toDoInterface>();

tittleValue = '';
descValue = '';    

addToList() {
  this.toDo.emit({ tittle: this.tittleValue, description: this.descValue });
}
```

I also made a [stackblitz project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-51235919), so you can see it in action.

Comment: @Nosheep if so please mark my answer as the correct one, thank you.